# How to monitor a process running in Linux virtual machine from host windows machine?

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, process-monitoring

I have installed a linux machine inside my Windows (using hyper-v server for that). Any idea how I could develop an application in c# which monitors a  process running inside Linux machine. So for example it would monitor a process called "XYZ" inside linux  and if that process was to go down and not exist it could simply display a red light in windows ?

Comment: Look into VMI (Virtual Machine Introspection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a small monitoring program inside linux which changes a flag in a database running on windows.

or change a file located in linux, which should be read from windows using some kind of file sharing ..

or run a small web server on linux to communicate from your program running on windows

Comment: Or have the monitor process communicate with the window-popping monitor process running in Windows.